# customizing layer control dialog

Tags: leaflet

By default the layer control dialog looks like this:

[image]

(from https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/example.html)

What if I wanted to make it look more like this?:

[image]

How might I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inspecting the DOM, it seems that you want to add your custom element inside `.leaflet-control-layers-list`, before `.leaflet-control-layers-overlays`.

With vanilla JS, you can achieve this using `.insertBefore` method, as following:

```
let layerControlContainer = document.querySelector('.leaflet-control-layers-list');
let layerOverlays = document.querySelector('.leaflet-control-layers-overlays');

let myInsert = document.createElement('span');
myInsert.innerHTML = 'Overlays';

layerControlContainer.insertBefore(myInsert, layerOverlays);
```

Check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9j7pveq0/

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is using [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-control-layers-overlays")[0].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin","<div>my title</div>")
```